# Is it true Smartas (Iyers) revere Apastamba and Badhuyana Dharmasutras

Tags: brahmins, dharmasutra, iyer

As per Wikipedia, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iyer#Rituals) it says "Iyer rituals comprise rites as described in Hindu scriptures such as Apastamba Sutra attributed to the Hindu sage Apastamba. The most important rites are the Shodasa Samaskāras or the 16 duties. Although many of the rites and rituals followed in antiquity are no longer practiced, some have been retained."Iyers generally lead orthodox lives and adhere steadfastly to their customs and traditions. Iyers follow the Grihya Sutras of Apastamba and Baudhayana. The society is patriarchal but not feudal.[37]" I am very interested if this is true historically. Any learned Iyer Brahmins or anyone with worthy references please provide.